# Summing entire column and using input string in path

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Value()


Dim fName As String
Dim fld As String
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Profit")
Set ws2 = wb1.Worksheets("Loss")

With ws1
Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End With

For i = 1 To Lastrow
  **fld = ws1.Cells.Value(i, "B")
    fName = Dir(fld & .Cells(i, "C").Value + "*.xls*")**
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(fld & fName, ReadOnly:=True)
    wb1.Worksheets("Revenues").UsedRange.Clear
    wb2.Worksheets("Latest").UsedRange.Copy  Destination:=wb1.Worksheets("Revenues").Range("A1")
    wb2.Close savechanges:=False

    With ws2
    Lastrow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    **ws1.Cells(i, "E").Value = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws2.Range("P2" & Lastrow2))**

Next i
End Sub
```

I am facing small errors at two places. First, the file from which I get the latest data is opened using Directory and File name provided as String in B & C column, but the compiler doesn't take it when I use. Secondly, when I sum the entire column it gives zero value always, don't know why. In short I take the file name and directory and place an output number(Sum up column) besides it. Also SUM(P:P) doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
fld = ws1.Cells.Value(i, "B")
```

two issues with this:

1. it's `.cells` that needs the cell reference, not `.value`
2. you're mixing `R1C1` with `A1` in your cell reference

Try it this way:

or:

```
fld = ws1.Range("B" & i).Value
```

You're repeating error #2 in all your references where you're using `.cells()`

**Additional Error:**

```
fName = Dir(fld & .Cells(i, "C").Value + "*.xls*")
```

In addition to error #2, above, you're using `+` for concatenation. VBA uses `&`.

```
fName = Dir(fld & .Cells(i, 3).Value & "*.xls*")
```

**NOTE:**

You may want to consider putting some error handling around the `Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(fld & fName, ReadOnly:=True)` line, since you're relying on a user to correctly enter a path (you're assuming it ends in a `\`) and a file name. The slightest typo and your `.Open()` will fail.

You may also consider searching for `FileSystemObject` to present the user with the Windows standard file dialog box so they can pick the file they want to have opened. That will ensure you get back a  (if they cancel) or a guaranteed valid path\filename since they selected something existing and didn't have to type it in.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also tell me as hpow can I included *.xls* as I am getting an error over there'

Comment: @Jain, see additional notes in my answer.